# Razor Class Library in ASP .Net Core 2.1.1

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I used to embed some of my Razor views for mailing in a class library which was using **ASP .Net Core 2.1.0-preview1-final** and it was working fine.

Here is the configuration in the .csproj file:
[image]

Since I upgraded the .Net Core version to 2.1.1 which is the final one, I can not use the embedded views anymore.

I know about the new Razor Class Library concept but I need to pass my views to a ViewRenderer service which basically converts the view to string to be sent as an email.

The viewrenderer service was finding the views before but now it doesn't find them and I get the following error:

**VIEW** does not match any available view

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the view locations code from the startup.cs (if any) and also the code that is calling the renderer with the view name. Also, I believe the stacktrace will tell you where it was looking for the view/cshtml

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the exact same issue, setting `CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory` to `true` in the csproj file fixed it. your csproj file should look like this :

```
...

<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>    

...
```